# как отловить ситуацию, когда программа была остановлена из среды разработки, например IntelijIdea?

Tags: java

Штатное завершение программы - отлавливает Listener
Аварийное - Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook)

А как отловить ситуацию, когда программа была остановлена из среды разработки, например IntelijIdea?

Comment: Пробовал дебажить??

Comment: да, я пробовал дебаг, но в эти блоки не попадаю. В качестве теста использую программу, которая создает временный файлик при запуске программы, а при завершении его уничтожает.

Answer (score 2):

Если запустить приложение в `Intellij Idea` и попытаться его оставить, нажав на красный квадратик.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Idea` генерирует сигнал прерывания операционной системы  и отправляет его java процессу. Этот сигнал можно обработать внутри программы. Делается это, следующим образом (справедливо для linux, для других ос название сигнала может отличаться):

```
  Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), new SignalHandler() {
        public void handle(Signal sig) {
            System.out.println("ой, меня кто то хочет остановить");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

Этот код добавляет обработчик для системного события `Interrupt from keyboard`, выводит сообщение в консоль и останавливает работу приложения.

Comment: Подскажите, для Eclipse код будет такой же или нужны дополнения?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov Я не знаю, какое он событие генерит, но думаю принцип тот же,  можно поэкспериментировать с названиями сигналов.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но не получается отыскать соответствующий сигнал от Idea в ОС Windows.